# Loadfactor and Capacity of hashmap

Tags: java

how to find the current load factor and Capacity of the hashmap?

```
Map m = new HashMap(10,1);

//but after lots of works

Here how to get current values.
```

Comment: Im pretty sure that the loadFactor doesn't change from construction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to be able get the load factor and capacity; they are implementation details of the hashmap class.  However, You can use reflection.  Try to avoid using it though, it is generally a bad idea.

```
Field f1 = m.getClass().getDeclaredField("table");
f1.setAccessible(true);
int capacity = f1.get(m).length;

Field f2 = m.getClass().getDeclaredField("threshold");
f2.setAccessible(true);
int currentLoadFactor = f2.get(m);
```

Answer (score 2):

Load factor will remain constant. From the  [documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

```
 The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased. The initial capacity and load factor parameters are merely hints to the implementation.
```

By looking at the documentation we can say that:

1. loadFactor is always lessthan or equal to 1.

2. size of Map is always less than or equal to (capacity * loadFactor)

So we can find current capacity by writing a code snippet like this:

```
 public static Integer findCurrentMapCapacity(Map m, Integer initCapacity, Float loadFactor){
    //default values: initial capacity=16 and loadfactor=.75 
    if (initCapacity==null){
        initCapacity=16;
    }
    if(loadFactor==null){
        loadFactor=0.75f;
    }
    boolean capacityFound=false;
    Integer capacity=initCapacity;
    Integer size=m.size();
    while(!capacityFound){
        if(size>capacity*loadFactor){
            capacity=capacity*2;
        }else{
            capacityFound=true;
        }
    }
    return capacity;
}
```